# EF Core how to get a DBContext in a class instance?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

The ASP NET Core project uses the Entity Framework Core.

From the method of the Home controller I call Task.Run for the method of the instance of the class `MyClass`, where I need to access the data from the database.

I tried to pass `_dbContext` to the constructor of the `MyClass` class, but I get the exception

> Cannot access a disposed object.

**HomeController**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowAllOrigin")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly DataBaseContext _dbContext;

   public HomeController (DataBaseContext dbContext)
   {
      _dbContext = dbContext;
   }

   [EnableCors("AllowAllOrigin")]
   [HttpPost("[action]")]
   public string UpdateBotSettings()
   {
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass(_dbContext);
      Task task = Task.Run(() => myClass.AnyMethod());
   }
}
```

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly DataBaseContext _dbContext;

   public MyClass(DataBaseContext dbContext)
   {
      _dbContext = dbContext;
   }

   public async void AnyMethodAsync()
   {
      MyData myData = _dbContext.AnyData.Where(d => d.id == 1).FirstOrDefault(); // <- exception
   }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

  string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionDB");
  services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options =>  options.UseSqlServer(connection));
  // another code
}
```

Can you please tell me how to access dbContext inside an instance of MyClass?

Comment: can you post a snippet from the Startup.cs that shows which scope is DbContext under?

Comment: Added by. Inside the controller, the data context runs without error.

Comment: Probably by the time your task runs, the context is disposed. Why not make the controller action `async` and use your service without the need to create a new `Task` ?

Comment: @IvanMladenov Part of the logic removed from the controller as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important mistake in your code is that you are using `async void` in your `AnyMethodAsync()` method of the `Myclass`. Don't use `async void` in your code, instead use `async Task`. Here is the details:  [C# – beware of async void in your code](https://theburningmonk.com/2012/10/c-beware-of-async-void-in-your-code/)

So write your `AnyMethodAsync()` as follows:

```
public async Task AnyMethodAsync()
{
   MyData myData = await _dbContext.AnyData.Where(d => d.id == 1).FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

Now you can register your `MyClass` to the ASP.NET Core DI container as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddScoped<MyClass>(); // <-- here it is

   string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionDB");
   services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options =>  options.UseSqlServer(connection));
   // another code
   services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Now use it as follows:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowAllOrigin")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly DataBaseContext _dbContext;
   private readonly MyClass _myClass

   public HomeController (DataBaseContext dbContext, MyClass myClass)
   {
      _dbContext = dbContext;
      _myClass = myClass;
   }

   [EnableCors("AllowAllOrigin")]
   [HttpPost("[action]")]
   public async Task<string> UpdateBotSettings()
   {
      await _myClass.AnyMethod();

      // rest of codes
   }
}
```

Comment: This is like using the `Service Locator` anti-pattern, which kinda kills the purpose of dependency inversion http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: Yes! I just gave him the solution to overcome to his problem. Otherwise I would suggest constructor DI injection.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Is it possible to learn more about the constructor DI injection?

Comment: @al.koval please see my updated answer and I am giving you some link to study DI in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @al.koval You can read this primarily : https://medium.com/volosoft/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-best-practices-tips-tricks-c6e9c67f9d96

Comment: @TanvirArjel Used solution with constructor DI. But I still got an error "Cannot access a disposed object" inside the class when trying to get to the data.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Thanks for the help! =)