# What is the problem with using directive and SQLite in the following situation? I got ObjectDisposedException, but just here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sqlite

I do not have any problems for example here:

```
using FooContext context = new FooContext();
context.RemoveRange(context.FooTable);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But I DO get ObjectDisposedException here when I use 'using directive' either with block (with {}, as before C# 8.0) either by writing the new form, without {}.

```
DbSet<FooThing> allResults;
using (FooContext context = new FooContext()) 
{
   allResults = context.FooTable;               
}
return allResults;
```

And again, no problems with the following:

```
FooContext context = new FooContext();
return context.FooTable;
```

What is the problem with my code and how could I use using directive without exceptions?

***EDIT:***

Now I'm trying to use DI.
I created a scaffolded item by choosing "...using Entity Framwork" in the menu in VS.

In the class that was created by VS, I have an instance of the DbContext class at the top:

```
        private readonly FooContext _context;

        public FooController(FooContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

I can use this object, it seems there is no problem with it.

But now I get:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type '<Namespaces of my app here>.FooContext' while attempting to activate '<Namespaces of my app here>.FooController'.`

I think that is because I did not injected the type to the appropriate container.
Where should I do this?

Should I do something here?

```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `DbSet<Foo>` instead of a `List<Foo>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`DbSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0), which is what `FooTable` is an instance of, is a table accessor. You return this instance is (which then used by something we assume) but the associated `DbContext` instance on which this instance relies on was disposed by your `using` block.

If you are using asp.net you should look into using a Dependency Injection framework (like AutoFac). You can then register your `DbContext` type, have it injected in your Controller, and AutoFac will dispose the `DbContext` instance at the end of the request.

Comment: How could I do that? Where could I learn about that? 
I searched a lot in the internet and I mainly used Microsoft's documentation and tutorials, and the only (understandable) thing I found is 
services.AddControllers(); in Startup.Configureservice().
I seems it is not enough.

After registering my DbContext type, I do not have to use 'using directive', and the DbContext class will be disposed automatically?

Comment: @BonEd - correct, you have the instance injected into in the constructor of your controller. Also based on this comment it seems you are using .net core. In asp.net core there is built in dependency injection framework that you could easily take advantage of.

Comment: Thank you, your comments helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your context is disposed when it exits the `using` statement.  There would normally be no problem with your `allResults`, but I would guess that you are trying to use a navigation property or related item on the results.  Your code will attempt to retrieve the data, but then it gets blocked because the `context` that was used to retrieve the data has been disposed.

Comment: There is only 1 table in the database. The table has a primary key, of course, but there are no foreign keys. Still can be the problem be caused by navigation properties? What should I do with them?

Comment: Ah, it's very possible that the context has not resolved the data.  At that point it is still an IQueryable object which is essentially just unresolved sql (more or less).  Try adding a `.ToList()` to the `allResults` object inside the using statement.

Comment: Thank you; now I understand the problem. Now I'm am trying to use ASP.NET built-in DI container instead of a lot of using directives, but I have other problems with that. :D

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems that this solves my current problem:

[EF Core how to get a DBContext in a class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781993/ef-core-how-to-get-a-dbcontext-in-a-class-instance)

Thank you, Igor for mentioning DI!

Finally I found this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0